# UIButton: crash on click

Tags: objective-c, crash, uibutton

Premise that I have already read all the similar S.O. threads and I have not found a good solution for me.

I've a controller with an imageView with a button, and works fine.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
[self.imageView setImage:image];
```

Then I add "A", interface derived from NSObject with a UIImageView and an array of "B":

```
A* a = [[A alloc] initWithImageView:self.imageView];
[A loadButtons];
```

**A.h**

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView;
- (void)loadButton;
@end
```

**A.m**

```
- (id)initWithImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView {
    self = [super init];
    self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.imageView = imageView;
    return self;
}

- (void)loadButton {
    B* b = [[B alloc] init];
    [self.myArray addObject:b];
    [self.imageView addSubview:b.button];
}
```

**B.h**

```
@interface B : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* button;
@end
```

**B.m**

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return self;
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
 ...
}
```

Now the problem is that when user click the button, application crash reporting no error on console, but moving on main:

```
0x10ab52900 <+1282>: movq   0xb56001(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010cdfd070: __stack_chk_guard
```

I can't understand where is the mistake!

Works if I add target on button directly from the main view controller

```
A* a = [[A alloc] initWithImageView:self.imageView];
[A loadButtons];
for(B* b in a.b) {
    [b.button addTarget:self action:@selector(bClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint for all exceptions. See where it breaks next time it crashes.

Comment: Already done, doesn't works..

Comment: where are you calling your `initWithDictionary:` method?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: In real program I've initWithDict, but in example just "init" is ok, I've edited question, sorry

Comment: is self.imageView a nib file?

Comment: Yes I started from new "Single view application" and in Main.storyboard I've added an ImageView to the existing ViewController (linked with IBOutlet in ViewController.m)

Comment: Do you actually have the `buttonClicked:` method implemented? The code that you claim works is referencing a method named `bClicked:`, not `buttonClicked:`. Which it is? And it would help if you posted the relevant stack trace, pointed out the actual line causing the crash, and posted the error message.

Comment: different name just for example, I used buttonClicked: on B.m (doesn't work), bClicked on ViewController.m (works). No error message, only a BAD_ACCESS..

Answer (score 0):

Purely looking at your A.h and A.m, there is a problem

```
- (id)initWithImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView {
    self = [super init];
    self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.imageView = imageView;
    return self;
}

- (void)loadButton {
    B* b = [[B alloc] init];
    [self.myArray addObject:b];
    [self.imageView addSubview:b.button];
}
```

Your variable b will be deallocated after loadButton method exits! So, even though you add b.button as subview to self.imageView, clicking on button will crash your program.

But in your second example,

```
A* a = [[A alloc] initWithImageView:self.imageView];
[A loadButtons];
for(B* b in a.b) {
    [b.button addTarget:self action:@selector(bClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

somehow, b is a property of A (why don't I see that in A.h)? Did you modify? If you modify A.h to contains a strong pointer to B then, the code will work because your b object is not deallocated.

Comment: Well, looking at it a second time, you did add your b to self.myArra (which is again not found in h file). You should produce all the relevant codes correctly.